# What is wrong with this values.yaml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm

im getting this error with this helm install

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: 
error validating "": 
error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http): 
missing required field "paths" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.HTTPIngressRuleValue
```

and this is my code for the values.yaml

```
  ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: ""
  annotations:
    #  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
       alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
       alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  hosts:
    - host: metabasea0000125955
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
            service:
              name: test
              port:
               number: 3000
          pathType: Prefix
```

i can't understand what im doing wrong

Comment: Please check the last line indentation. This isn't a valid YAML file.

Comment: That Helm values file on its own isn't enough to understand what might be going wrong.  The Helm chart template code should be creating an Ingress object, and the output of that is incorrect.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], in particular making sure to include the template code that creates the Ingress, and possibly also trimming out unnecessary bits of the values file?